# What does the phrase "builds on the lore of the game" mean here?

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning, phrases, phrasal-verbs

I am not sure about the meaning of the phrase "builds on the lore of the game" in the following sentence:

> It’s interesting to see how the community **builds on the lore of
>   game**.

The fans are invited to share their inputs on prototypes of the game. The developer praises their creativity and commitment. I know the lexical meanings of the phrase ["build on"](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/build%20on) but they don't seem to fit here.

Comment: When you couldn’t find “build on” in that dictionary, did you try any [other dictionaries](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/build+on)?

Answer (score 1):

You have identified the verb **to build**, and it *does* fit here.  The word **on** is a contraction of **upon**, and is being used to describe that something is being built on top of something that already existed.

**The lore of the game** is the collection of storytelling elements that explain the game world's fictional history, as experienced by the characters of the game.

> [**lore**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/lore)
>
> 1. archaic : something that is taught : lesson
> 2. something that is learned:
>
>    1. knowledge gained through study or experience
>
>       - the lore of religious architecture
>    2. traditional knowledge or belief
>
>       - tribal lore
> 3. a particular body of knowledge or tradition
>
>    - the lore of baseball heroes

The developers have asked for end-users to share their feedback into the story and the storytelling elements, and have possibly allowed that feedback to shape the story further.

The community has therefore been able to **build** (construct additional storytelling elements) **on** top of the existing lore (that the developers have created).

You might see the use of **build on** (or **build upon**) elsewhere, more literally, as:

- They **built** their house **on** land that their grandparents owned.
- I will **build** my castle **on** top of a large hill.
- Never **build on** top of sand.